# How to calculate $\int_a^bx^2 dx$ using summation?

Tags: calculus, summation, riemann-sum

So for this case, we divide it to $n$ partitions and so the width of each partition is $\frac{b-a}{n}$ and the height is $f(x)$.

\begin{align}
x_0&=a\\
x_1&=a+\frac{b-a}{n}\\
&\ldots\\
x_{i-1}&=a+(i-1)\frac{b-a}{n}\\
x_i&=a+i\frac{b-a}{n}
\end{align}

So I pick left point, which is $x_{i-1}$

I start with 
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{b-a}{n}f\left(a+\frac{(i-1)(b-a)}{n}\right)
&=\frac{b-a}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \left(a+\frac{(i-1)(b-a)}{n}\right)^2\\ 
&=\frac{b-a}{n}\left(na^2+ \frac{2a(b-a)}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(i-1)+\frac{(b-a)^2}{n^2} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(i-1)^2\right)
\end{align}

Here I am stuck because I don't know what$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(i-1)^2$is (feel like it diverges). Could someone help?

Comment: No finite sum can diverge, so that is not your problem.

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(i-1)^2 = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}i^2$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula

Comment: You must be careful here to prove the formula for the summation using methods that don't invoke any integral calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum that is of concern is multiplied by $\frac1{n^3}$ and the limit therefore converges.  Then, proceeding, we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(i-1)^2=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^2$$

We can evaluate the sum on the right-hand side of $(1)$ using a number of approaches.  The approach we present here exploits telescoping series.  We note that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{n-1}\left((i+1)^3-i^3\right)=n^3 \tag 2$$

If we expand the terms in the sum in $(2)$, we find that

$$3\sum_{n=0}^{n-1}i^2+3\sum_{n=0}^{n-1}i+\sum_{n=0}^{n-1} 1=n^3 \tag 3$$

whereupon solving for the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{n-1}i^2$ and using $\sum_{n=0}^{n-1}i=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{n-1}i^2&=\frac{n^3-n-3\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}{3}\\\\
&\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{=\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}}
\end{align}$$

Dividing by $\frac1{n^3}$ and lettgin $n\to \infty$ yields $\frac13$ as expected!

Adding this to the other terms and letting $n \to \infty$ yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{n\,a^2(b-a)}{n}+\frac{2a(b-a)^2\,\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}{n^2}+\frac{(b-a)^3\,\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}}{n^3}\right)=\frac{b^3-a^3}{3}}$$

Answer (score 2):

It is a well-known formula that

$$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

So, in your case,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n (i-1)^2 &= 0^2 + 1^2 + \cdots + (n-1)^2 \\
&= 1^2 + \cdots + (n-1)^2 \\ \\
&= \frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i-1)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(i^2-2i+1) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}i + \sum_{i=1}^{n}1$$
You should be able to take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (i-1)^2$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n (i^2-2i+1)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n i^2-2\sum_{i=1}^ni+\sum_{i=1}^n1$$
$$=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-2\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n$$
$$=\frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}-n(n+1)+n$$
$$=\frac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{6}-n^2$$
$$=\frac{2n^3-3n^2+n}{6}$$
$$=\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}$$